# Stored procedure returns different results when called from another server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have created a stored procedure in Server1 that is returning the correct results
Then on Server2 I just execute the Server1 stored procedure by linked server.

At first the return results at Server2 are the same as Server1.

But after 1 or 2 days, Server2 returns some null values in some of the data. But Server1 is still returning the correct results.

Result Server1:

```
Id  Name       Location     Age
1   Alex       USA          20
2   Bob        UK           23
3   David      JP           25
4   Don        UK           24
```

Result Server2:

```
Id  Name       Location     Age
1   Alex       USA          20
2   Bob        NULL         NULL
3   David      NULL         NULL
4   Don        UK           24
```

I'm only able to temporally resolve this by recompile the Server1 stored procedure.
Than the Server2 will get the correct result, but after 2 days later the same problem occur again.

20190920 update..... include the sample of stored procedure query.

FYI: Some NULLvalue appear in those column CASE statement

```html
all the @... is input 
@output is declare as Table. 
above here is a lot of insert statement into the @Output table

SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT tbla.SiteName,tbla.FromWorkCenter ,tbla.Category,tbla.MaterialName,tbla.OperSeq
  ,tbla.FromOperSeq,tbla.StepIndex,tbla.FromStepIndex,SUM(tbla.CFqty) CFQty
   FROM (
    SELECT tbl.SiteName 
    ,CASE
    WHEN tbl.RouteName like '%REWORK%' THEN 'PS-'+tbl.ToWorkCenter
    WHEN isnull(tbl.FromWorkCenter,'WRH')='WRH' THEN 
    (Select CASE Source WHEN 'TWH' THEN 'TWH' WHEN 'LWH' THEN 'LWH' ELSE 'WRH' END AS Source
    from DIM_MATERIAL ddm WHERE ddm.MaterialName=tbl.MaterialName
    AND ddm.MainCategory_wk = (SELECT TOP 1 dc.key_wk FROM DIM_Category dc WHERE dc.Category=TBL.Category))
    else 'PS-'+dw.WorkCenterName END AS FromWorkCenter
    ,Category ,tbl.MaterialName,tbl.RouteName
    ,CASE tbl.OperSeq WHEN '0' THEN '10' ELSE tbl.OperSeq END AS OperSeq
    ,CASE rsd2.OperSeq WHEN '0' THEN '10' ELSE rsd2.OperSeq END AS FromOperSeq
    ,CASE WHEN rsd.RouteName LIKE '%REWORK%' THEN (
      SELECT TOP 1 c.StepIndex FROM DIM_MATERIAL a
      JOIN DIM_MaterialStructure b on a.Key_wk=b.Material_wk
      JOIN DIM_ROUTESTEPDETAIL c on b.RouteName=c.RouteName and c.OperSeq=tbl.OperSeq and OperSeqFlag='TRUE'
      join AUDIT_JOB d on b.audit_id = d.audit_id and d.post_end_dt <= @Date
      WHERE a.MaterialName=tbl.MaterialName
      ORDER BY d.post_end_dt desc
      )
    ELSE rsd.StepIndex end StepIndex
      ,CASE WHEN rsd.RouteName LIKE '%REWORK%' THEN (
      SELECT TOP 1 c.StepIndex FROM DIM_MATERIAL a
      JOIN DIM_MaterialStructure b on a.Key_wk=b.Material_wk
      JOIN DIM_ROUTESTEPDETAIL c on b.RouteName=c.RouteName and c.ToOperSeq=tbl.OperSeq and OperSeqFlag='TRUE'
      join AUDIT_JOB d on b.audit_id = d.audit_id and d.post_end_dt <= @Date
      WHERE a.MaterialName=tbl.MaterialName 
      ORDER BY d.post_end_dt desc
      )
    ELSE rsd2.StepIndex end FromStepIndex
    ,(SUM(BFQty)+SUM(RtnFromQty)+SUM(RecQty)-SUM(IssueQty)-SUM(RtnToQty)-(SUM(RejQty))+SUM(TrnQty)+SUM(AdjQty)+SUM(SCQty)) AS CFQty 
    
    FROM @Output TBL
    JOIN DIM_MATERIAL DM ON TBL.MaterialName=dm.MaterialName AND dm.MainCategory_wk = (SELECT TOP 1 dc.key_wk FROM DIM_Category dc WHERE dc.Category=TBL.Category)
    LEFT JOIN DIM_ROUTESTEPDETAIL rsd ON rsd.RouteName=tbl.RouteName AND rsd.OperSeq=CASE tbl.OperSeq WHEN '0' THEN '0' ELSE tbl.OperSeq END 
     AND OperSeqFlag='TRUE' AND rsd.Site= @Company
    LEFT JOIN DIM_ROUTESTEPDETAIL rsd2 ON rsd2.RouteName=tbl.RouteName AND rsd2.ToOperSeq=CASE tbl.OperSeq WHEN '0' THEN '0' ELSE tbl.OperSeq END 
     AND rsd2.OperSeqFlag='TRUE' AND rsd2.Site = CASE tbl.SiteName WHEN 'SIS' THEN 'SIS' ELSE 'INT' END
    LEFT JOIN DIM_WORKCENTER DW ON rsd.WorkCenter_wk=dw.key_wk
    WHERE tbl.SiteName=@Site 
    GROUP BY tbl.SiteName, tbl.FromWorkCenter ,tbl.Category ,tbl.MaterialName ,tbl.RouteName,tbl.OperSeq, tbl.StepIndex,dm.Key_wk,rsd.StepIndex,tbl.RouteName, tbl.Material_WK,rsd2.OperSeq,rsd2.StepIndex,dw.WorkCenterName,tbl.ToWorkCenter, rsd.RouteName
  ) tbla
  where tbla.CFQty<>0
  GROUP BY tbla.SiteName, tbla.FromWorkCenter, tbla.Category ,tbla.MaterialName,tbla.OperSeq,tbla.FromOperSeq,tbla.StepIndex,tbla.FromStepIndex
) b
where b.CFQty<>0
ORDER BY b.MaterialName ,b.OperSeq ,b.SiteName ,b.FromWorkCenter ,b.Category ,b.FromOperSeq ,b.StepIndex ,b.FromStepIndex
```

Comment: can you post your stored procedure ?

Comment: Could you show us:  
  
a. the `@Date` assignment, and
b. `@Output` query?

I'm assuming `@Company` and `@Site` are inputs to the SP.

Is `@Date` also an input?

Comment: all the @... is input and @output is declare as Table.

Comment: Just a quick questions, does this table has clustered index ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.
it turn out to be the data sequence is different when query from local and remotely

Result Server1:

```
Seq Name       Location     Category
1   Bob        UK           20
2   Bob        UK           23
```

Result Server2:

```
Seq Name       Location     Category
1   Bob        UK           23
2   Bob        UK           20
```

So when filtering some data is not joined properly as result null